# How accurate are people at determining the validity of a signature?

Tags: physical-signature

Is there any scientific survey about this?

I could imagine an experiment like this:

- 100 people provide at least 3 times their signature (e.g. with different pens)
- Each of them gets all 3 example signatures of e.g. 2 other people and has to forge the signature.
- At least 3 different experts get one real signature and the remaining 8 ones. They have to tell which ones are real, which ones are fake. They are NOT told how many real / fake ones there are.

Was something like that done before?

Comment: https://teresadeberry.com/handwritten-mechanical-methods-creating-non-genuine-signatures/ plenty of research has been done

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is about existing research, which is very easily found by googling the question's title.

Comment: I don't get that logic: you're choosing a question that doesn't have an answer for 3 years... because it's so easy to answer?